# ImageView does not show up when added to a TableRow programmatically

Tags: java, android, imageview, tablerow

Here are the relevant code bits:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/cards_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:fillViewport="false" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/cards_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/test_card"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/cards_distance"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/card_back" />

        </TableRow>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

and

```
private void addCard(Drawable d) {
        TableRow container = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.cards_container);
        ImageView card = new ImageView(this);

        card.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        card.setPadding(R.dimen.zero, R.dimen.zero, R.dimen.cards_distance, R.dimen.zero);
        TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        card.setLayoutParams(params);
        card.setImageDrawable(d);
        card.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        container.addView(card);
}
```

I'm positively sure the Drawable I'm trying to add is not null, has the bounds properly set, the alpha set to 255, and fits properly. I've tested this by applying it to test_card instead of trying to add new ImageViews, which works perfectly.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: pass youractivty.this for context

Comment: @edwin The method is top-level anyway, but I guess it is good style to pass [Activity].this. In my case, nothing has improved though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an hour of tinkering with the code, it turns out `setPadding()` actually takes ints and not resource references as arguments, and that's what was messing it all up.

So basically all I needed to do was change:

`card.setPadding(R.dimen.zero, R.dimen.zero, R.dimen.cards_distance, R.dimen.zero);`

to

`card.setPadding(0, 0, 5, 0);`